# How can I make Microsoft Word ignore all spelling error caused by Arabic Letter Alef Maksura (0x649, ی)?

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check, dictionary, arabic

When I write Arabic, I always use Arabic Letter Alef Maksura (0x649, ی) instead of Arabic Letter Yeh (0x64a, ي) if it comes at the end of the word which causes spelling error. I tried to add the words to the dictionary, but it was a tedious task, and even after a while, all the added words were removed, and it showed me them as errors again.
How can I make it ignore this specific type of errors? Or how can I add them permanently to the dictionary, and transfer them to another device if possible?

Comment: Is there a language where ی the proper character?  I know Word not Arabic grammatical rules

Comment: @Ramhound There are two schools of Arabic writing, one that always uses ى, and the other one that uses both ى and ي. I am from the first one.

Comment: Well that partially answered my question.  Do these schools have distinct names?

Comment: @Ramhound The first one is the Egyptian school along with Quran standards, and the second one is the Syrian school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can make Word ignore this through Options > Proofing > When correcting spelling in Microsoft Office programs, I unchecked "Arabic: Strict final yaa".